# abort() has been called while LevelDB PUT()

Tags: c++, leveldb

I'm trying to `put()` binary data of large scale files into the leveldb using c++ library.
While `put()` operation working on the leveldb warning `abort() has been called` is generated if I execute my code.

```
FILE* file;
WriteOptions woptions;
woptions.sync = true'
DB* db;
Options options;
options.create_if_missing = true;

DBPATH.assign(DBName);
char key = '1';

Status s = DB::Open(options,DBPATH,&db);
assert(status.ok());
fopen_s(&file, "target.jpg", "rb");
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
long long int size = ftell(file);
rewind(file);

char* buffer = (char*)calloc(1, size);
if(buffer == NULL) printf("mem error\n");
fread(buffer, size, 1, file);

Slice slice(buffer, size + 1);
Slice key_in(key, sizeof(char)+1);
status = db->Put(woptions, key, slice);
assert(status.ok());

free(buffer);
slice.clear();
key.clear();
fclose(file);
delete db;
```

I've tried to print the status to figure out what's the problem. But before printing status, the abort() message pops out. So I think there must be some problem in PUT(). Do I need to change config or any other envs?
Or is there the size limitation of handling data exist on leveldb...?
I tried berkeleydb and rocksdb in the same way,but no warning message popped. I looked up the doc of each DBs. And I can't find how to handle BLOBs at leveldb doc unlike other DBs. Now I wonder if the leveldb supports the BLOBs.....!

Comment: `assert()` will call `abort` if the condition is not met. you could try to log the status code to see if it gives you any more details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But the warning message is different from assert message. I still have the same problem even if I remove assert()...! Assert messages show where is the problem in code, but this case, only abort() message printed!!

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]! Also, step through the code in a debugger and state where the error happens.

Comment: "_Now I wonder if the leveldb supports the BLOBs_" - Yes, it's a generic _Key_ / _Value_ store and, afaik, the _Key_ s and _Value_ s are just a bunch of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the LevelDB API I think this is what's wrong:

```
char key = '1';
// ...
Slice slice(buffer, size + 1);             // + 1 is wrong
slice key_in(key, sizeof(char)+1);         // `key_in` is invalid and +1 is wrong
status = db->Put(woptions, key, slice);    // and `key_in` is unused
```

The *Key* you use is not a `Slice`, it's a `char`.

If you only want a single `char` for the *Key*:

```
char key = '1';
// ...
Slice slice(buffer, size);                 // correct size
Slice key_in(&key, sizeof key);            // take the address and size of the key
status = db->Put(woptions, key_in, slice); // and use `key_in`
```

Alternatively, create your *Key* `Slice` from a `char*`:

```
char key[] = "1";
// ...
Slice slice(buffer, size);                 // correct size
Slice key_in(key);                         // `key_in` created from C string
status = db->Put(woptions, key_in, slice); // and use `key_in`
```

---

I also suggest simplifying the code. Don't use `calloc`. Use a `std::vector<char>` instead.

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

// Read the whole file into a vector<char>
std::vector<char> get_file_content(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream is(filename, std::ios::binary);

    if(!is) throw std::runtime_error(filename + ": " + std::strerror(errno));

    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};
}

int main() {
    // Your current code up until you open the database.
    // ..
    Status s = DB::Open(options,DBPATH,&db);
    assert(status.ok());

    char key = '1';
    auto buffer = get_file_content("target.jpg");

    Slice key_in(&key, sizeof key);
    Slice slice(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    status = db->Put(woptions, key_in, slice);

    std::cout << status.ToString() << '\n';

    delete db; // the only cleanup needed

    std::cout << "Done\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you kind answer!  But I till have a problem on PUT...!

Comment: @JeongHwanIm Which one of the many `Status` codes does the `Put` return? `kNotFound`, `kCorruption`, `kNotSupported`, `kInvalidArgument` or `kIOError`? Did you copy what I wrote exactly like I wrote it?

Comment: Please try to copy what I wrote, _exactly_ as I wrote it and see what that does before making changes to it. I have no `char key[10]` or `int int_key`. I only changed the definition of `key` to `char key[] = "1";` and then I made the correct declaration of `key_in` and also _used_ `key_in` in the `Put`

Comment: std::cout<<status.ToString()<<endl; does not print message. I mean, before print the status, abort() message pops out first. I think there's a problem while put operation works.

Comment: I tried both, slice(buffer, size) and slice(buffer, size+1), both of them still print abort() message

Comment: @JeongHwanIm Are you using any of my suggestions _exactly_ as I wrote them? Can you paste your current code somewhere where I can take a look at it (like https://pastebin.com/) ?

Comment: I followed your code, using isreambuf_iterator, the abort() doesn't pop but the value of file is not read. I mean, if I write the data of buffer, nothing is written. And also, I tried ifstream APIs, instead of fread, but the abort() message pops.

Comment: @JeongHwanIm I don't understand what combination of things you are trying. You can't use `istreambuf_iterator`s without an `istream` (like an `ifstream`) - so what did you do?. Can you please share your code so I can take a look at it?